# Sending out notification email to user on user-defined date in php

Tags: php

I am making a feature on my website that allows the user to enter a task they need to finish by a certain date. The website will then notify them by email when it gets near the date, defined by the user (1 day before due date, 2 hours before due date and so on..) I am totally new to notifications and am unsure how to ask this question but here it is in an example of what I want done...

**In an example:**

1. The user types in "Need to call boss."
2. The user enters in the date selector, May 31st at 11:00 AM.
3. And then clicks the "Notify me 1 day before"
4. They enter their email and click submit.

My website will then notify them by email on May 30th at 11:00 AM reminding them to call their boss...

I have looked around and have noticed somethings pointing to CRON jobs.. I looked at that and am unsure if that is the way to go...

Thanks for the time!

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP script to execute at certain times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981036/php-script-to-execute-at-certain-times)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your server. What OS, what access you have and a bunch of other stuff.

On Linux, a cron job would work. On Windows server, Task Scheduler would do the same job. Basically, you need a mechanism to call a script that will read through your database and send emails depending on conditions being true.