# Self Executable Code In PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I need a script which can exceute automatically when Current date reached.
Forexample:
when CurrentDate > DueDate 
Add Surcharge with Total Dues.

### Note:

Add Surcharge with Only those customers who did'nt pay their monthly bill.

Can anyone give me some hint or any kind of Source. Thanks

Comment: Do some research cronjobs and PHP.

Comment: For periodic execution you can use a cronjob - the checks etc. must be made in php / MySQL. Please try yourself and come back if you got any more detailled questions.

Comment: thank you to both of you. Typoheads dhh

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP script to execute at certain times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981036/php-script-to-execute-at-certain-times)

Comment: Your request is like saying: 'Give me a new car' to a total stranger. SO is not a site where you can simply request scripts.

Comment: sorry dear please see last line. @peter i don'nt need ur script

Answer (score 0):

write a cron every minute

```
* * * * * /path/to/php /var/www/html/a.php
```

or every 24th hour

```
0 0 * * * /path/to/php /var/www/html/a.php
```