# Timed PHP script executions

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not quite sure how to ask this, but here goes. I have a MySQL table that has the following fields: `dateRegistered` and `expiryDate` .The fields are quite self explanatory, now what I am trying to achieve is have a php script be executed when the date on the `expiryDate` is reached. I really don't know where to start. Example:

```
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
| userID |    dateCreated      |      expiryDate     |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  52    | 2015-10-08 13:30:17 | 2015-10-09 13:30:17 |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

When the date under `expiryDate` is reached, a php script gets triggered. Is this possible? Are the ways

Comment: Yes it possible. Use CRON in PHP.

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP script to execute at certain times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981036/php-script-to-execute-at-certain-times)

Comment: Thank you so much for your responses guys, I will look into them. Much appreciated

Comment: I do this using cron (I'm guessing if you're on windows you'd use Scheduled Tasks) to run a script which then checks the dates and acts accordingly. Perhaps not the best or most efficient way, but it does work well.