# function that updates the database every 10 min

Tags: php, linux, phpmyadmin

I have two databases.  Below is the code that I am using to get information from the first database.

```
$myrow = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(uploaded) FROM peers",$db);
$sum = mysql_fetch_array($myrow);
$c = $sum[0] / 1000000;
$d = $c / 1000000;
$l = round($d,3);


echo "<p>UP: $l TB</p>";


$myrow1 = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(downloaded) FROM peers",$db);
$sum1 = mysql_fetch_array($myrow1);
$a = $sum1[0] / 1000000;
$b = $a / 1000000;
$k = round($b,3);

echo "<p>DW: $k TB</p>";
```

I need to add this information to my second database and update it every 10 min with new fresh information from first database. I am using phpmyadmin.

Comment: You can use a cron (linux) or scheduled task (windows) to execute your script every 10 minutes. More info setting those up in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120228/php-running-scheduled-jobs-cron-jobs

Comment: I recommend a very slow (drinking bird)[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinking_bird] tapping the enter key on a dedicated machine, or a JavaScript `setInterval`.. just leave the browser open all the time

Comment: how can i do this without cron?

Comment: mulekula: I have edited your post to fix a couple of English syntax errors and make it a little bit clearer.
No need to apologize about your English level.. my Russian level is worst for sure :)

Comment: ok i use Debian. so i create a cron task and then i need to create a php file thet must copy a date to a new data base?

Comment: @mulekula Why are you asking us? You asked how to execute a function every 10 minutes.. whatever you do with that script/function is up to you.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very generic so I will try to answer for all scenario
You shoud create a process that run every 10 minutes (cron if you use Linux, scheduled task if you use windows)

If you use **Linux** you can

- **If you really want to use PHP, create a PHP script and call it using php command line** or (much worst) create a php page that do what you want and have CRON to call it every 10 mins using LYNX browser.
- Create a program in c/python/etc. that connects to first DB, query info, and writes to second.
- Create a bash script that use mysql commandline to connect to DBs and do the same. (This has the advantage of not having to program)

If you use **Windows** you can:

- Create a scheduled task in C# or vb.net or similar
- Create a scheduled task using powershell

Answer (score 1):

Use cron jobs for updating your information in DB.

[cron jobs or PHP scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268044/cron-jobs-or-php-scheduler)

[http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs/)

Comment: how can i do this without cron?

Comment: If you don't use CRON you must do a respawn daemon that every 10 mins executes proper code... exactly the same as CRON does.
Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: ok thx you! i create a cron job and its work! But i have some trouble with php) how create a request to update a table in date base?

Comment: its a good example? $myrow2 = mysql_query ("UPDATE 'stat_up' SET `dw` = '$k', `up` = '$l'",$db);