# Auto-delete database entry after user defined time?

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm making a Pastebin kind of a thing in PHP (ran on an Ubuntu server with Apache and MySQL). The user uses an HTML form to paste in whatever they want (+ a title in a separate input box) and I want to give the user the option to have their paste automatically deleted after a time they get to choose from a selection in a dropdown box.

How can I do that?

Comment: write a script that checks the deletion time in the columns, and [execute it periodically with cron](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job#2369).

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268044/cron-jobs-or-php-scheduler

Comment: @JeffPuckettII Will look into this. Thanks.